# Target file of nuget package doesn't proceed .dll file

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

We changed our Azure pipeline from (legacy) csproj pack to nuget pack. In the process, it seems that a .dll which is located at the root folder of my project isn't copied despite it being mentioned in the .target file. From what I've read it should work without extra referencing the (.dll) file in the nuspec itself. Regardless, in both cases my "PreserveNewest" option, of that file, in the target isn't recognized/applied however.

My nuspec (part) looks like this:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Release\MyProject.dll" target="lib/net48"></file>
    <file src="CertEnroll_Interop.dll" target="content"></file>
    <file src="bin\Release\MyProject.xml" target="lib/net48"></file>
    <file src="MyProject.targets" target="Build" />
  </files>
```

The targets:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\content\CertEnroll_Interop.dll">
            <Link>CertEnroll_Interop.dll</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
 </Project>
```

And the csproj of the project which installed my package:

```
<Import Project="packages\MyPackage.1.0.0\build\MyPackage.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\MyPackage.1.0.0\build\MyPackage.targets')" />
```

Now my question are why doesn't the "settings" for the .dll apply and is a reference in the nuspec required?

This is for a Net Framework 4.8 package and the .dll build is set to "content".